# bash - fork a process without the "complete" notification

Tags: bash

Just a quick question that I'm having trouble Googling for some reason.

When I fork a process in bash like this:

```
$ mything &
```

And it completes 10 seconds later, it interrupts my terminal like this:

```
[1]+  Done          mything
```

Is there a way to disable this? I want to run it in the background but I want it to never come back and tell me anything, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `disown` after forking
2. Run it in `screen`: `screen -dm mything`

The second one has the advantage of you being able to re-attach and see the output before it finishes, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Try using disown...

Try the following - which will not return text....

```
sleep 5 &
disown %1
```

This will never tell you the job has completed.

Answer (score 0):

A subshell is probably the cleanest approach:

```
( sleep 1 & )
```